# Shell script - Keep double quotes in middle of a parameter without using \ to escape

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I am writing a shell script to help me running with the react-native project, my script has the following parts:

```
#some steps to create $calculated_value...

os_type=$1
shift
script="$calculated_value react-native run-$os_type $@"
$script
```

When I type this command in terminal:

```
./scripts/run ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

I expect the script should execute the following command at the end:

```
"$calculated_value" react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

However, the scripts now execute this command:

```
"$calculated_value" react-native run-ios --simulator=iPhone 6
```

which the double quotes have disappeared, and terminal just read the simulator without the "6".

I have tried replacing the `$@` with `$(for i;do echo ${i@Q};done;)`
but it gives me the error: `line 25: ${i@Q}: bad substitution`

**I know I can add `\` before the double quotes to escape it

but just want to see if there are any solutions I can do to skip adding `\`.**

**---------------------------------------------- EDIT INFO ----------------------------------------------**

Now I am using `eval` inside the script in order to run the command with a file location.
Inside the scripts, it contains the below steps:

```
...some calculation to get $envfile

os_type=$1
shift

run_script="ENVFILE=$envfile react-native run-$os_type $@"
eval $run_script
```

Inside my `package.json`:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "./scripts/dev"
  }
}
```

In my real case, when I type:

```
npm run dev ios -- --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

What I expected is:

```
ENVFILE=env/tw.dev react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 6"
```

But now the command miss the double dash argument.

Comment: Escaping won't help you. Use an array instead

Comment: Sorry but I don't get your meaning, could you write an example for me? Thanks.

Comment: Don’t put commands in variables. Variables are for data, not commands. See [bashFAQ#50: I'm trying to put a command in a variable, but the complex cases always fail!](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: @tripleee  In my case, the double dash is inside the argument. Therefore the question you quoted for me is not working.

Comment: Why do you think the location of the dashes is important? This is about quoting. But I'll add another popular duplicate; this is a relatively common question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider eliminating the 'script' intermediate variable

```
os_type=$1
shift
"$calculated_value" react-native "run-$os_type" "$@"
```

The quotes around 'run-$os_type', and '$@' will address proper expansion of parameters with spaces (or other 'magic' characters: *, ?, ...).

It's not clear what is the value of "$calculated_value", answer assume it's the path to a program (without extra arguments). If it may contain arguments, or options, you will probably have to remote the quotes around it.

**EDIT 2019-10-10:**

With the original code ("script=... $@"), bash will break the input arguments (the '$@') into tokens in the assignment command. Possible alternative to prevent this step is:

```
script="$calculated_value" react-native "run-$os_type"
$script "$@"
```

Comment: Sorry, I am using eval before the script, as there is a file location on the calculated value. Is there a way to use your solution in eval? Thanks.

Comment: Can you post the full eval command, it is not referenced in the question

Comment: Hello, I just update my real case on the question. Thank you.

Comment: @WingChoy note proposed solution was to replace 'script=some-command ; $script' with 'eval some-command'. Using 'eval' on '$script' may not help, quotes will be stripped in this sequence